# NullPointerException in LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, localbroadcastmanager

I've tried to update my list after the SMS arrives. I get the receiver correctly, but when i try to send the receiver to my class I get the following error in the some phones.

```
05-20 09:50:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8873): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 09:50:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
05-20 09:50:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
05-20 09:50:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
05-20 09:50:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 09:50:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
05-20 09:50:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
05-20 09:50:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 09:50:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 09:50:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-20 09:50:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-20 09:50:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my code works correctly in some phones.

I've send Broadcast with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(filtering);
intent.putExtra(RESULT, result);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And I get receiver in the following code:

```
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

                if (bundle != null) {
                    int resultCode = bundle
                            .getInt(NormalIncommingTextService.RESULT);

                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        RefreshList(getActivity());

                    }
                }

            }
        };
```

I've registered and unregistered my receiver in onResume and onPause with this code:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(Home.receiver,
                new IntentFilter(NormalIncommingTextService.NOTIFICATION));
// registerReceiver

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(Home.receiver); // unregisterReceiver
```

I've search a lot in SO but couldn't find a working solution.

thanks in advance for your time

if you want to see any part of my code ask me.

`NormalIncommingTextService.NOTIFICATION` is same with `filtering` in my code.

**// EDIT**

this is line 297 @ `LocalBroadcastManager`

```
br.receivers.get(j).receiver.onReceive(mAppContext, br.intent);
```

more info on [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.java) but i don't know what is the problem with that. this error happening on `FragmentActivity` class while updating one Fragment data, i test it on Activity and worked fine

PS: in some phone I don't have any problem with updating data on `FragmentActivity`

**//Answer**

I've fix this problem, with using normal `BroadCastReceiver` instead of `LocalBroadcastManager`